# Texts that define the derivative as the "Anti-integral"....?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

Every text that I read starts by defining differentiation then integration... but does anyone know if there is one that goes the other way?  Also is there any harm in taking this approach.... to me, the current approach is only done because it has always been this way. I say this because I believe that this approach would allow a neater flow of logic in teaching calculus.

Comment: I think the idea behind this is that differentiation is usually far easier than integration and allows the practical introduction of limits easier.

Comment: How would you integrate by parts without differentiation? Too much trouble, I think.

Comment: Apostol's Calculus text books go through integration before differentiation.

Comment: Courant and Apostol study integration before derivatives. But they define derivatives in the classical way, not as an anti-integral. Have you developed your project to do it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richard Courant's [Differential and Integral Calculus](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Differential-Integral-Calculus-Vol-One/dp/4871878384/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1358776873&sr=1-1) discusses the integral before differentiation.

Answer (score 3):

as Mike noted: Apostol, *[Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471000051)* (1967) begins with integration.

But then, later, derivatives are defined in the usual way, *not* somehow obtained as *anti-integral*.